# How to calculate FPS using GPU in Python

Tags: python-3.x, computer-vision, video-streaming, gpu, frame-rate

I am working on a computer vision project where all the processing or inferencing is happening on GPU. I need to calculate live FPS I am getting from the video stream. This video stream cane be video file or RTSP video stream.

I wrote a simple logic to calculate FPS. It looks like below:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fps_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
fps = 0
total_frames = 1

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    total_frames = total_frames + 1

    """
    All the processing and 
    inferencing happens here
    """

    fps_end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_diff = fps_end_time - fps_start_time
    fps = (total_frames / time_diff.seconds)

    fps_text = "FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps)
    print(fps_text)
    cv2.putText(frame, fps_text, (5, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow("Application", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

Just to explain above logic, I am taking `fps_start_time` before starting the inferencing. Once inferencing is done, I am taking `fps_end_time` and then subtracting the end time with start time and dividing time diff with frames to get FPS. This works fine if you are doing all your inferencing on CPU. But if your inferencing is happening on GPU, it shows incorrect value.

I have a custom made hardware where GPU is of very high end while CPU is low and thus when inferencing I can see in the output video, there is no lag/delay but FPS still remains around 6-7 and in actual it looks like 25-30. This is happening because, CPU usage while inferencing is always at around 95% so FPS is low. If we do the FPS using GPU, which is at 50-60% most of the time then we might get correct values.

Is there any pre-built libraries or methods available which we can use to get FPS of GPU?

Comment: have a same question, no other solutions?

Comment: your biggest mistake is throwing datetimes around. use `time.perf_counter()`. apart from that, I can't reproduce your claims.

Comment: I am not sure of what `time.perf_counter()` does but the basic idea is to calculate the time used to process 1 frame and to do this, we can use any library.

Answer (score 0):

1. I guess you are doing it right, so basically, FPS = 1/('Current Operations time' - 'Previous Operations Time').
2. Also check if your camera is actually streaming 60 fps. You can do it in OpenCV using this.

   `cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)`

   `fps =  cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)`
3. Most of the WebCam are locked at 30 fps.

If you have figured up a solution, do let me know.

Comment: I have not yet found any solution for this. Above code works fine for CPU but not for GPU